# debian grub2 so such device error

Tags: debian, boot, grub2

I installed debian 7.11 on a Pentium-MMX system with two disks sda and sdb on sdb1 and used the MBR of sda for grub2. Sda is marked in the bios as the boot hard disk. The installation went without any error.

The first time I started the new system I got "error: no such device ....." after the
Welcome to GRUB! message and landed in grub rescue. The ls command in grub rescue shows
the following message: (hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos1) but nothing about hd1. So I assume grub2 does not see the second hard disk.

I booted a debian 7.11 live system and mounted sdb1. I verified that the uuid from sdb
is the same as in grub.cfg. I mounted dev sys proc for the chroot command and changed via chroot in my new debian 7.11 system.

grub-install /dev/sda and update-grub did not show any error, but after booting the
second time into debian 7.11 I get the same no such device error

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The second hard disk (sdb) was not defined in the bios.

Set it from type = none to type = auto and grub2 does find sdb1

Comment: This question belongs on SuperUser. It has *nothing* to do with Linux or Unix.